# Header rearrange/change on scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, header

I've looked everywhere on how to do this particular thing. But I'm attempting to create a header like on: http://pinkpeonies.com/. Where the logo moves over, and the navigation floats right when the user scrolls far enough down. I can't seem to find how to do it. How would I create a header like this? What would be the best way?

Comment: it is manage in jquery when u scrool down the header class will be change and its style also change in jquery and css

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#header").addClass("scroll-down");
}
else {
    $("#header").removeClass("scroll");
}
});
```

and you can style scroll-down class in css